# Get values from Json Array in VB.Net

Tags: json, vb.net

Thanks in advance
I have a json array like below
`[
    {
        "Name": "abc",
        "Age": "15",
        "Gender": "M"
    },
    {
        "Name": "def",
        "Age": "16",
        "Gender": "M"
    },
    {
        "Name": "ghi",
        "Age": "17",
        "Gender": "M"
    }
]`

i need to extract data, please advice

Comment: You can deserialize to a `List(Of class)` objects. Is this all the JSON you have, or there's more of it? If that's the case, post the rest of it. To build class objects from the JSON structure, you can use the corresponding Visual Studio's `Paste Special` tool, if the structure is simple. You can find on-line tools that do a better job, if the structure is more complex. What tools are you planning to use? Json.Net? JavascriptSerialier? System.Text.Json? Other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should help get you started.
First we create the `Person` object like so

```
Public Class Person
Public Property Name As String
Public Property Age As String
Public Property Gender As String

Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return "Name: " + Name + " Age: " + Age + " Gender: " + Gender
End Function
End Class
```

This will be were we store the persons properties.
We will also [override](https://www.dotnetperls.com/tostring-vbnet) the `ToString()` so we can get all of the properties we want when displaying the objects information.

Now we will `Deserialize` the payload into a `Person Array` using [Newtonsoft Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), this is a very popular library to help you with any work needed for Json Data, you will need to install the package via Nuget

```
Dim payload = "[{""Name"": ""abc"",""Age"": ""15"",""Gender"": ""M""},{""Name"": ""def"",""Age"": ""16"",""Gender"": ""M""},{""Name"": ""ghi"",""Age"": ""17"", ""Gender"": ""M""}]"
Dim personCollection() = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Person())(payload)
```

Once that is complete, we can [loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement) through each of the items in `personCollection` and display the results to the console.

```
For Each person As Person In personCollection
    Console.WriteLine(person.ToString())
Next
```

Hopefully this helps. I used a Console Application for this example.
**Full Example**

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim payload = "[{""Name"": ""abc"",""Age"": ""15"",""Gender"": ""M""},{""Name"": ""def"",""Age"": ""16"",""Gender"": ""M""},{""Name"": ""ghi"",""Age"": ""17"", ""Gender"": ""M""}]"
    Dim personCollection() = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Person())(payload)

    For Each person As Person In personCollection
        Console.WriteLine(person.ToString())
    Next

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub

End Module

Public Class Person
Public Property Name As String
Public Property Age As String
Public Property Gender As String

Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return "Name: " + Name + " Age: " + Age + " Gender: " + Gender
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: This worked as i expected , Thanks.I need to capture this json in POST Web Api, i passed from fiddler but getting nothing, please advice

Comment: @RoadsideRomeozz Your question has be answered. Please accept AndrewE's answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. What you ask in your comment is a new question and should be posted as such.